# hosted kmz file stopped rendering on google maps

Tags: google-maps, kmz

I have a kmz file located at www.la2ba.com/interface/LA2BA.kmz and it was being used by both a mobile app and a website through google maps (http://www.la2ba.com/Route/). Over a month ago it stopped working although nothing has changed, and I'm unable to figure out why. I can still download the file and view it in Google Earth without problems.

Any help you can offer would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With KmlLayer I get a status: FETCH_ERROR, on your server, not sure why:
http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.la2ba.com/interface/LA2BA.kmz

It works if I put a local copy on my server:
http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/LA2BA.kmz

and it seems to work OK with geoxml3 (the local copy):
http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmztest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/LA2BA.kmz

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. I'll contact the hosting co. and see what they say. Will report back..

Comment: I've tried setting the mime type via an htaccess file, that didn't change anything either. The host says all is well on the server side, and as proof placed a sample kmz file at http://www.la2ba.com/interface/sample.kmz , which does work.

Comment: Then, I placed the file at googlesites: https://sites.google.com/site/sunnyunal/LA2BA.kmz . That works on google maps but returns DOCUMENT_NOT_FOUND in your testing method (KmlLayer (?)).

So there seems to be something wrong in my file that my server doesn't like, but others may overlook.

In any case, I'd be happy to hear from someone who could help me fix this in an affordable way. 

Thanks again!

Comment: The KmlStatus returned for your problem file is `FETCH_ERROR | The document could not be fetched.`, hard to say why Google's servers return that, it can certainly be fetched by a browser (I downloaded it).  My server seems to be able to serve it without issues.  The 2 header sniffers I use (http://web-sniffer.net/, http://www.rexswain.com/httpview.html) seem to return reasonable headers and seem to be able to access it.